# Can I use the Revised Ranger in Adventurers League?

Tags: dnd-5e, dnd-adventurers-league

I am planning to build an archer for my next D&D character for Adventurers League. I will be going three levels in fighter to pick up the Battle Master Archetype and from there I am considering multiclassing as a ranger. I have been away from D&D for the better part of 2 years and am unfamiliar with the ruling regarding the revised ranger from Unearthed Arcana in league play. **My question is thus: can I use the revised ranger in Adventurers League and if not, is their any point in going ranger otherwise?** I remember that the ranger was really underpowered and I know Unearthed Arcana addressed this issue. Also just to note, I am not planning on going beast master.

Comment: The part about "is there any point in going ranger otherwise" isn't really a good fit for the Stack--that looks much more like a discussion prompt than it does a tightly-focused answerable question. Ignoring that, I think the rest of the question's covered by the duplicate-linked one.

Comment: and I should have mentioned in the first instance: if the linked question *doesn't* answer things for you, please edit *this* question to make clear the difference and then flag it for reopening. And (in reverse order of importance) welcome!